# How to fix jpa one to many

Tags: spring, jpa

Need to fetch data from one table to another.I performed jpa one to many mapping. But id cannot fetched. Where is my mistake?

I have tried mapping using one to many and many to one concepts but can't able to fetch data from one table to another

```
User.java

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User  implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "User_ID")
@GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")

private String id;

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Long phoneNumber;

@NotNull(message="Password is compulsory")
@Email(message = "Email is invalid")
private String email;

private String password;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

Set<Data> data  = new HashSet<Data>();

public Set<Data> getData() {
    return data;
}


public void setData(Set<Data> data) {
    this.data = data;
}


public User() {
    super();
}
```

Data.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "data")
public class Data  implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "DataID")
@GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")

private String  id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "User_ID")
private User user;


public Data() {
super();
}


public User getUser() {
return user;
}


public void setUser(User user) {
this.user = user;
}
```

DataController.java

```
@PostMapping("/data/{userId}")
public Data createData(
    @PathVariable(value= "userId") String userId,
    @Valid @RequestBody Data data) {

return userRepository.findById(userId).map(user -> {
    data.setUser(user);
    return dataRepository.save(data);
}).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("userId" + userId + 
"not found"));
}
```

Results in no error but can't able to fetch user id

Comment: You mean `findById(userId)` doesn't get you anything? Or the response from createData doesn't contain the user id?

Comment: response from createData doesn't contain the user id